# is it possible to change the default direction of a ViewPager Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

It is possible to override the action of switching screens of a ViewPager that by default drags to the sides (from left to right and vice versa)
to pass the screen with movements from top to bottom and from bottom to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default direction to top-to-bottom by using the `orientation` attribute of ViewPager2.

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:orientation="vertical" />
```